# Your Instant App APKs contain the domain 'xxx.com' that is already in use by another app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, google-play-console

My first instant app contains my domain and work fine but now I want to use my domain in another instant app, I upload My second full app then upload my second instant app, unfortunately I meet this error，does anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: I find the answer, [A website can declare associations with multiple apps within the same assetlinks.json file](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html#multiple-apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/instant-app-links.html#how_app_links_for_instant_apps_are_different): "*Only one instant app can be declared for each website domain.*"

You can use subdomains like `app1.host.tld`, `app2.host.tld`, `etc` for each app to workaround this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the domain of my old instant app from xxx.com to xxx.xxx.com and use xxx.com in new instant app. Everything work fine.