# Publishing Android Instant App: Domain is used by another app

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to publish an Instant app but got this error on review and release page.

> Your Instant App APKs contain the domain 'xxx.xxx.com' that is already in use by another app.

If I remove the `intent-filter` that contains the domain, then this error will go away. So looks like it's the only issue in my app bundle.

However, that domain is not used by any other app. Also, I set up the assetlink.json file correctly, as I'm able to pass the test in App Links Assistant.

What are the other possibilities that Google may report this error to me?

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936214/your-instant-app-apks-contain-the-domain-xxx-com-that-is-already-in-use-by-ano

Comment: @DeveloperSunshine Thanks. I saw this too. I did similar thing as the original poster did. I removed the domain from the old instant app and use it for my new instant app, but the error persists. Maybe it takes a couple days for Google to accommodate the update?

Comment: @MillerDong Hi, was You able to resolve this problem? Currently I am facing the same issue in my Project.